# How to save data in directly to the database in vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I am encountering a problem in my Visual Basic.NET code in saving a data directly to an Microsoft Access database. Here is the code I have tried to accomplish my problem:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
Dim cnn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ching13\Desktop\watta1.mdb"

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using dbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cnn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Try
            dbConnection.Open()
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Log-In( Username, [Password] ) VALUES (@user, @pass)"

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@user", DbType.String))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@pass", DbType.String))

            cmd.Prepare()

            cmd.Parameters("@user").Value = TextBox1.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@pass").Value = TextBox2.Text

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            dbConnection.Close()


        End Try
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""

    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

Here is my revised Visual Basic code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim cnn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ching13\Desktop\watta2.accdb"


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using dbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cnn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
        dbConnection.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        cmd.Connection = dbConnection
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Log-In( Username, [Password] ) VALUES (@user, @pass)"

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@user", DbType.String))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@pass", DbType.String))

        cmd.Prepare()


        cmd.Parameters("@user").Value = TextBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters("@pass").Value = TextBox2.Text

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dbConnection.Close()


        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""

    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: And what's the error you're encountering?  You need to provide at least *some* information.  (Hint: You're explicitly *ignoring* exceptions in your `Catch` block.  Exceptions contain very useful information and shouldn't be ignored.  There's a good chance the system is trying to tell you exactly what's wrong, and you're just not listening.)

Comment: Not seeing anything to give me a clue.As a PS you don't need to close the connection and that catch block is well naughty...

Comment: Without it you would get a null reference exception I think, given what Sir Tim spotted. Which is why try Catch end is frowned upon...

Comment: Sir, what my problem is that the data that I want to insert or add in my database is not adding. The code wasn't working.

Comment: @user3195853  why has your db changed? in the first code you posted it was `watta1.mdb` and your updated code is `watta2.accdb`

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the problem is that you're not assigning the `Connection` to the `Command`. You can either use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yeecx59%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or the [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.connection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
cmd.Connection = dbConnection
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Log-In( Username, [Password] ) VALUES (@user, @pass)"
```

Comment: thank you for the answer sir,, but the program is still not working.

Comment: @user3195853: What happened after you have removed the empty catch block? What is the next error? Empty catch blocks are a code smell since they hide important information ... from you  but not from the user.

Comment: Sir,, I remove the try catch.. And I don't know what's the next step I'll be doing.. I will just show you my codes:

Comment: @user3195853: do you get an exceptio? Have you used the debugger? What does `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` return? Assign it to an `Int32` variable to see if a record was inserted, then it returns 1.

Comment: Sir,,it's just been two weeks since I start programming.. So, I can't really understand your explanation sir. Please give me a code

Comment: @user3195853: i don't know the problem. Not assigning a connection to a command was definitely causing an exception. But i don't know what problems you have now. That's why i've asked you if you get an excpetion when you try to execute the code. Exceptions have a message and a stacktrace. The former identifies the problem and the latter the line where it occured. A debugger allows to stop the execution of code to inspect values of variables, so it can be very helpful to locate problems ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx)s a tutorial).

Comment: Well, Thank you sir. for giving your efforts and time. :)